# Conexión genérica a base de datos php

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

quiero hacer una aplicación php que realice consultas en diferentes bases de datos. Una es postgresql y la otra es mysql. Me gustaría saber si se puede crear un objeto genérico o con herencia para realizar las consultas indistintamente de la base de datos (ya que las llamadas a los métodos son disitintas) o si es mejor comprobar a que base de datos voy a hacer la consultar y llamar al método indicado para esa base de datos. Es que veo que hay bastante código repetido e igual se puede hacer con herencia pero no termino de verlo claro.

Comment: Entiendo que te refieres a la clase [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.pdo.php) de PHP, la cual tiene disponibles estos drivers: https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.drivers.php para distintas bases de datos.

Comment: @masterguru sii justo era lo que buscaba, gracias!